# Jenkins Unable to reach Sonarqube Local host

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I'm having connectivity issue between my Jenkins and Sonarqube localhost, during the build my Jenkins pipeline job is failed with below error

Note : i enabled firewall rule 9000 but still its failing

```
03:10:33.722 DEBUG: Download: http://sonarqube:9000/batch/index
03:10:33.780 ERROR: SonarQube server [http://sonarqube:9000] can not be reached
03:10:33.780 INFO: ————————————————————————
03:10:33.780 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
03:10:33.781 INFO: ————————————————————————
03:10:33.781 INFO: Total time: 0.587s
03:10:33.799 INFO: Final Memory: 3M/121M
03:10:33.799 INFO: ————————————————————————
03:10:33.800 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ScannerException: Unable to execute SonarQube
```

My localhost Sonarqube is up and running in my machine and also i can able to browse it http://localhost:9000

```
--2019-12-30 10:33:26--  http://localhost:9000/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:9000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html.3’

index.html.3                              [ <=>                                                                   ]  34.74K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2019-12-30 10:33:26 (231 MB/s) - ‘index.html.3’ saved [35575]
```

Note : All the jenkins configuration also done

```
1) Manage Jenkins –> Global Tool Configuration –> SonarQube Scanner configured, please find the attached image.sonar-scanner Jenkins configuration

2) Configure SonarQube server in Jenkins, this will communicate SonarQube Server authentication.

Log in into your SonarQube Server and find following under user bar Go to My Account –> Security –> Generate Token

Sonar-server token jenkins authentication
```

can you please some one help me on this issue ?

Comment: Your Jenkins host seems to be targetting `http://sonarqube:9000` but your curl command is against `http://localhost:9000/`. Is this difference intentional?

Comment: Hi Mc1arke, I resolved this issue, i configured in-correctly hostname in jenkins pipeline script, i have updated my jenkins script like this  http://dns_name:9000 then its started to working on it.